# How to convert csv to Json using expression transformation in informatica?

Tags: json, oracle, etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have a csv file, I am converting this to Json array format. Below are the row wise operations in expression transformation for the two fields.

```
region
country

    Json(output port): '{'||'"region": '||'"'||Region||'",'||'"Country": '||'"'||Country||'"'||'},'
    output:
    {"region": "Australia and Oceania", "Country": "Tuvalu"},
```

This output is saved in a text file with session file properties as fixed width.

second mapping expression:

```
JSON(input)
V_JSON_start(variable port):INSTR(JSON,'{',1,1)
V_JSON_end(variable port):instr(JSON,'}',1,10)
O_Json(output port):'['||substr(JSON,V_JSON_start,V_JSON_end)||']'
```

output:
[{"region": "Australia and Oceania","Country": "Tuvalu"},
{"region": "Central America and the Caribbean","Country": "Grenada"}]
when I try to fetch next 10 records as json, it pulls 20 records instead of ten
below is the expression:

```
JSON(input)
    V_JSON_start(variable port):INSTR(JSON,'{',1,11)
    V_JSON_end(variable port):instr(JSON,'}',1,20)
    O_Json(output port):'['||substr(JSON,V_JSON_start,V_JSON_end)||']'
```

Kindly look into this and correct where i am missing.

input: flat file(csv with two fields region and country))
expected output:(5 sessions each session 10 records in json format)
eg., [{"region";"value","country":"value"},
{"region":"value","country":"value"}]
session1(csv to json) -->session 2--session3--session4--session5--session6(all parallel sessions using the  file of 1st session 5 records in json format)

Comment: Should be `...port):instr(JSON,'}',11,20)` instead of ` V_JSON_end(variable port):instr(JSON,'}',1,20)`

Comment: I have tried to use  V_JSON_start(variable port):INSTR(JSON,'{',1,11)
    V_JSON_end(variable port):instr(JSON,'}',11,20), still i get 20 records instead of ten and moreover at the end i see spaces
{"region": "Australia and Oceania", "Country": "Tuvalu"} ,         ] 
I should not get ',' or extra spaces, the 11 might be starting character from where it starts, should be someother.

Comment: You can use Source qualifier SQL to control number of rows. But the requirement is unclear 1. what youre trying to do? 2. input and expected output? 3.are all rows concatenated into same file or youre generating one file for one row.

Comment: My source is a flat file. In the first session i am converting all the records into a json format like
{"region": "Australia and Oceania", "Country": "Tuvalu"},
{"region": "Austria", "Country": "ilu"}, so one into txt file(set fixed width in session level)
in the next session i am using this txt file as source as single string and using above expression operations fetching part of the string in a json format appending '[',']' to it. using instr i am not able to fetch correctly the next records.

Comment: updated question with input and required output